# The txt file in my GUI is causing the program not to work "Exception in thread "main"

Tags: java, user-interface

Whenever i update the txt file the program doesnt work 
im not sure where exactly the problem is, im still a begginer in this.
but when i run the program this is exactly what i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3    
        at coursework.AllNotes.readAllNotes(AllNotes.java:42)   
        at coursework.AllNotes.<init>(AllNotes.java:22)   
        at coursework.CourseWork.<init>(CourseWork.java:51)  
        at coursework.CourseWork.main(CourseWork.java:56)
C:\Users\rc1903v\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Code snippet:
this the main class :

```
 public class CourseWork extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

        CommonCode cc = new CommonCode();
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JTextArea txtNewNote = new JTextArea();
    JTextArea txtDisplayNotes = new JTextArea();
    JTextField search = new JTextField();
    ArrayList<String> note = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> course = new ArrayList<>();
    JComboBox courseList = new JComboBox();
    String crse = "";
    AllNotes allNotes = new AllNotes();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This is required for the coursework.
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Racha Chaouby");
        CourseWork prg = new CourseWork();
    }

    // Using MVC
    public CourseWork() {
        model();
        view();
        controller();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if ("Close".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
        }
        if ("Course".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
            crse = courseList.getSelectedItem().toString();
            System.out.println(crse);
        }
        if ("Exit".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if ("NewNote".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
            addNote(txtNewNote.getText());
            txtNewNote.setText("");
        }
        if ("SearchKeyword".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
            String lyst = allNotes.searchAllNotesByKeyword("", 0, search.getText());
            txtDisplayNotes.setText(lyst);
        }
        if ("Coursework".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
            CWDetails cw = new CWDetails();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("keyTyped not coded yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("keyPressed not coded yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("keyReleased not coded yet.");
    }

    private void model() {
        course.add("COMP1752");
        course.add("COMP1753");
        course.add("MATH1110");
        crse = course.get(0);

        //Note nt = new Note();
        //nt.noteID = 1;
        //t.dayte = getDateAndTime();
        //nt.course = crse;
        //nt.note = "Arrays are of fixed length and are inflexible.";
        //allNotes.allNotes.add(nt);
        //nt = new Note();
        //nt.noteID = 2;
        //nt.dayte = getDateAndTime();
        //nt.course = crse;
        //nt.note = "ArraysList can be added to and items can be deleted.";
        //allNotes.allNotes.add(nt);
    }

    private void view() {
        Font fnt = new Font("Georgia", Font.PLAIN, 24);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu note = new JMenu();

        note = new JMenu("Note");
        note.setToolTipText("Note tasks");
        note.setFont(fnt);

        note.add(makeMenuItem("New", "NewNote", "Create a new note.", fnt));
        note.addSeparator();
        note.add(makeMenuItem("Close", "Close", "Clear the current note.", fnt));

        menuBar.add(note);
        menuBar.add(makeMenuItem("Exit", "Exit", "Close this program", fnt));

        // This will add each course to the combobox
        for (String crse : course) {
            courseList.addItem(crse);
        }
        courseList.setFont(fnt);
        courseList.setMaximumSize(courseList.getPreferredSize());
        courseList.addActionListener(this);
        courseList.setActionCommand("Course");
        menuBar.add(courseList);

        this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
        // Setting up the ButtonBar
        JButton button = null;
        button = makeButton("Document", "Coursework",
                "Open the coursework window.",
                "Coursework");
        toolBar.add(button);

        button = makeButton("Create", "NewNote",
                "Create a new note.",
                "New");
        toolBar.add(button);
        button = makeButton("closed door", "Close",
                "Close this note.",
                "Close");
        toolBar.add(button);
        toolBar.addSeparator();
        button = makeButton("exit", "Exit",
                "Exit from this program.",
                "Exit");
        toolBar.add(button);

        toolBar.addSeparator();
        // This forces anything after it to the right.
        toolBar.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

        search.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(6900, 30));
        search.setFont(fnt);
        toolBar.add(search);
        toolBar.addSeparator();
        button = makeButton("search", "SearchKeyword",
                "Search for this text.",
                "Search");
        toolBar.add(button);

        add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel pnlWest = new JPanel();
        pnlWest.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pnlWest, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        pnlWest.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        txtNewNote.setFont(fnt);
        pnlWest.add(txtNewNote);

        JButton btnAddNote = new JButton("Add note");
        btnAddNote.setActionCommand("NewNote");
        btnAddNote.addActionListener(this);
        pnlWest.add(btnAddNote);

        add(pnlWest, BorderLayout.WEST);

        JPanel cen = new JPanel();
        cen.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cen, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        cen.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        txtDisplayNotes.setFont(fnt);
        cen.add(txtDisplayNotes);

        add(cen, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setTitle("Coursework");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setVisible(true);  // Needed to ensure that the items can be seen.

    }

    private void controller() {
        addAllNotes();
    }

    protected JMenuItem makeMenuItem(
            String txt,
            String actionCommand,
            String toolTipText,
            Font fnt) {

        JMenuItem mnuItem = new JMenuItem();
        mnuItem.setText(txt);
        mnuItem.setActionCommand(actionCommand);
        mnuItem.setToolTipText(toolTipText);
        mnuItem.setFont(fnt);
        mnuItem.addActionListener(this);
        return mnuItem;
    }

    protected JButton makeButton(
            String imageName,
            String actionCommand,
            String toolTipText,
            String altText) {

        //Create and initialize the button.
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setToolTipText(toolTipText);
        button.setActionCommand(actionCommand);
        button.addActionListener(this);

        //Look for the image.
        String imgLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir")
                + "\\icons\\"
                + imageName
                + ".png";

        File fyle = new File(imgLocation);
        if (fyle.exists() && !fyle.isDirectory()) {
            // image found
            Icon img;
            img = new ImageIcon(imgLocation);
            button.setIcon(img);
        } else {
            // image NOT found
            button.setText(altText);
            System.err.println("Resource not found: " + imgLocation);
        }

        return button;
    }

    private void addNote(String text) {
        allNotes.addNote(allNotes.getMaxID(), crse, text);
        addAllNotes();
    }

    private void addAllNotes() {
        String txtNotes = "";

        for (Note n : allNotes.getAllNotes()) {
            txtNotes += n.getNote() + "\n";
        }
        txtDisplayNotes.setText(txtNotes);

    }

    public String getDateAndTime() {
        String UK_DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
        String ukDateAndTime;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        SimpleDateFormat uksdf = new SimpleDateFormat(UK_DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
        ukDateAndTime = uksdf.format(cal.getTime());

        return ukDateAndTime;
    }

}
```

Code snippet:
i still have another class which is the note class
but i think the main problem is coming from the allnotes class because whenever i click on the error it takes me to the allnotes class for some reason:

```
public class AllNotes extends CommonCode {

    private ArrayList<Note> allNotes = new ArrayList<>();
    private String crse = "";
    private int maxID = 0;

    AllNotes() {
        readAllNotes();
    }

    public int getMaxID() {
        maxID++;
        return maxID;
    }

    private void readAllNotes() {
        ArrayList<String> readNotes = new ArrayList<>();

        readNotes = readTextFile(appDir + fileSeparator + "Notes.txt");
        System.out.println(readNotes.get(0));

        if (!"File not found".equals(readNotes.get(0))) {
            allNotes.clear();
            for (String str : readNotes) {
                String[] tmp = str.split("\t");

                int nid = Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]);
                Note n = new Note(nid, tmp[1], tmp[2], tmp[3]);
                allNotes.add(n);

                if (nid > maxID) {
                    maxID = nid;


                }
            }
        }
        maxID++;
    }
    //else {
    // allNotes.clear();
    // for (String str : readNotes) {
    // String[] tmp = str.split("\t");
    //Note n = new Note();
    //n.setNoteID(Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]));
    //n.setCourse(tmp[1]);
    //n.setDayte(tmp[2]);
    //n.setNote(tmp[3]);
    //allNotes.add(n);
    //}

    //}
    // }
    public void addNote(int maxID, String course, String note) {
        Note myNote = new Note(maxID, course, note);
        allNotes.add(myNote);
        writeAllNotes();
    }

    public ArrayList<Note> getAllNotes() {
        return allNotes;
    }

    private void writeAllNotes() {
        String path = appDir + fileSeparator +"Notes.txt";
        ArrayList<String> writeNote = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Note n : allNotes) {
            String tmp = n.getNoteID() + "\t";
            tmp += n.getCourse() + "\t";
            tmp += n.getDayte() + "\t";
            tmp += n.getNote();
            writeNote.add(tmp);
        }
        try {
            writeTextFile(path, writeNote);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Problem! " + path);
        }
    }

    public String searchAllNotesByKeyword(String noteList, int i, String s) {
        if (i == allNotes.size()) {
            return noteList;
        }
        if (allNotes.get(i).getNote().contains(s)) {
            noteList += allNotes.get(i).getNote() + "\n";
        }

        return searchAllNotesByKeyword(noteList, i + 1, s);
    }

}
```

Comment: Remember indexes of Java arrays start at 0, not 1.

Comment: Can you add the code of all the classes to your question?

Comment: Check the length of the array tmp, based on that read the values.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to parse a line with only 3 tabs.

Comment: @AlexanderKaschta i just added the classes

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku i changed this part                                                   
 int nid = Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]);
                Note n = new Note(nid, tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2]);
                allNotes.add(n);                                                                  but now the whenever i enter a text it only shows the date and time  not the text it self